# How do i make a daily error log file, for a live stream, using FFMPEG?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using FFMPEG to convert a stream on the fly, but i want to log all the errors in file. The file should be generated daily, whilst the stream is 24/7.
What command can i use?

At the moment i have used this command:
ffmpeg -i ... commands ..... -loglevel warning -report 
I want the file to be written every day for the live stream, but each day makes it own file, instead of one file.
Thanks

Comment: Please share with us how you attempted to log the errors.

Comment: so i had my command ffmpeg -i ... commands .... -loglevel warning -report, this only creates one file that writes into it all the time. I have been looking around if anyone has done it but i haven't seen anyone.

Comment: Ok, you should add those details to the question so other readers will see that and hopefully be able to help you.

Comment: @Broadcasting123 are you looking for [logrotate](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate)?

Comment: @aergistal Can that be done, because i am using CMD for my command?

Comment: @Broadcasting123 There's at least a port for Windows, [logrotatewin](https://github.com/plecos/logrotatewin)